# What determines the order of my contacts on the frequent contact toolbar?

Tags: contacts, whatsapp-messenger

I am seeing a contact in recently contacted friends in whatsapp to whom I have not sent a message for a week now. All the other contacts are chronologically arranged except for him. Why is this happening? Is it that he is spying on me and my phone is sending him my history automatically? Or is it normal to be so?

Comment: Why would you think your phone is sending him your history?

Comment: Not knowing the real algorithm: I'd say "frequent" is defined as "number of accesses per time". Maybe you contacted him more frequent in the past, and your more recent contacts have not yet caught up?

Comment: Is he one of your "starred" contacts?

Answer (score 2):

I *think* from reading the source code [here](http://androidxref.com/4.2.2_r1/xref/packages/providers/ContactsProvider/src/com/android/providers/contacts/ContactsProvider2.java#5110) and [this line](http://androidxref.com/4.2.2_r1/xref/packages/providers/ContactsProvider/src/com/android/providers/contacts/ContactsProvider2.java#5173) and also from reading the code in the Contacts application that the "Frequently Contacted" list in the Contacts application orders the contacts by the number of times that you've called them. That's the `DataUsageStatColumns.USAGE_TYPE_INT_CALL` bit. This is also assuming you're using the default Contacts application but since you didn't specify I assumed you were.

So it must be that you've called this particular friend more than any others. To test this try and make a large number of calls to the next person in the list and see if it overtakes the top person.

It could also be the case that you've 'starred' him. If you go on his contact profile at the top there's a star. If this is white then it means that you've favourited him which means he will always appear at the top of the "Frequently Contacted" screen. Just uncheck the star and he'll go away.

There is also the option to clear the list if you like, just click on the Action Menu or your menu button and select "Clear frequents".

Comment: i am refereing to whatsapp application here.no. of calls made effect whatsapp frequent contact too...?

Comment: @avi It could well do, but since it isn't open source I can't really say.